# Making multiple li selectable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to do an `ul` where multiple `li` elements are selectable at the same time.
How can I do this?

```html
<div class="pre-scrollable items">
  <ul>

    <li class="solide">
      <p class="option">
        Mustermann Max 1234567 Informatik <input class="float-right checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
      </p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li tabindex="2" class="solide white">
      <p>
        Musterfrau Lisa 7654321 MCD <input class="float-right checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
      </p>
    </li>
    <br>

    <li tabindex="2" class="solide ">
      <p class="option">
        Mustermann Max 1234567 Informatik <input class="float-right checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
      </p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li tabindex="2" class="solide white">
      <p>
        Musterfrau Lisa 7654321 MCD <input class="float-right checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is there a br in you UL? That is invalid HTML/

Comment: Your code seems to work as intended. See: https://codepen.io/04kurisu/pen/gOOyepL . Also, remove those `<br>` tags, as @epascarello said that's invalid HTML

Comment: If you need to add space between rows try targeting them with css and adding some margin-top to them.

Comment: As others have mentioned your code seems to work fine. Are you sure you are asking the right question?

Comment: The point is i can only select one list at the same time, but i want to select like 3 lists at the same time because i want to do later a funkction to delete some lists by selecting them

Comment: Do you mean when submit the form, you only get one `checkbox` value? because right now you only have one list, which is `ul`. If this the case, Just give the `<input>` different `name` attribute.